# USB Camera to conect in android phone

Tags: android, react-native, cordova, ionic-framework

I need the development of an application mobile to take pictures.
But the camera is external so that it will be connected by usb cable in the tablet android.

What the better technology to create this app?

I did not find the solution for this to react native and Cordova.

Comment: can you please Explain more about your scenario?? Why you need External camera?

Comment: Hello! I got the same problem as yours, do you have any solution for now? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To use the native feature of the mobile device, you need to add the native plugin
to your mobile app project. Then you can call the native camera function by javascript (Javascript bridge)

In your ionic project, you can use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera

You can use Chrome Dev Tool(Remote device) to debug your app on the real device, but if you want to debug the native plugin, you have to use Android Studio.

Or if it's a react project, you can use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera